# IntelliJ Crashing in MAC (Apple chip) with Operation Not Permitted

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am new to setup of IntelliJ community edition in Mac.

My IntelliJ is crashing in MAC with Operation Not Permitted message in log file. Any suggestions ?

Reproducing Steps:

1. Created a project
2. Press command shift A to launch action dialog. start typing something.
   Crash

Found below entries in log file:

```
023-12-21 12:07:59,693 [  35152]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.i.l.LocalFileSystemBase - /User/<user>/Library/Application Support/com.apple.LaunchServicesTemplateApp.dv: Operation not permitted
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/com.apple.LaunchServicesTemplateApp.dv: Operation not permitted
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.NioFiles.readAttributes(NioFiles.java:187)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PlatformNioHelper.visitDirectory(PlatformNioHelper.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemImpl.listWithAttributes(LocalFileSystemImpl.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemImpl.lambda$new$0(LocalFileSystemImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.DiskQueryRelay.accessDiskWithCheckCanceled(DiskQueryRelay.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemImpl.listWithCaching(LocalFileSystemImpl.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshWorker.partialDirRefresh(RefreshWorker.java:322)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshWorker.processQueue(RefreshWorker.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshWorker.lambda$parallelScan$0(RefreshWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
```

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the system crash logs and java_error_in_*.log files from the user's home directory.

Comment: contacted intellij support.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while setting up PyCharm on my new M1 air.

I think I solve this by following steps.

1. Mac system settings > privacy & security > files and folders
2. Allow intelliJ to access the directory that error log says not permitted.
3. If this not work, I recommend to allow intelliJ to get full disk access.

Hope this work for you :)